# LoaderMax Error opening image URL from wordpress

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

Error opening URL 'http://test.myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/premi_logo.jpg ?purpose=audit&gsCacheBusterID=1313725194183'

```
var picloader:LoaderMax =new LoaderMax({name:"mainQueue", onProgress:EventLoader, onComplete:ImageLoaded});
    for (var i:uint; i < news_xml.news.length(); i++)
    {
        picloader.append(new ImageLoader(news_xml.news[i].imagelink. @ path, {name:'photo_'+i}))
    }
            //picloader.auditSize =false;
    picloader.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe you have a space (" ") at the end of the URL that you're passing into the ImageLoader.

Also, if you want to avoid the file size auditing, you can set LoaderMax.defaultAuditSize = false. There are some tips and tricks at http://www.greensock.com/loadermax-tips/ and dedicated forums at http://forums.greensock.com